# Ruby bubble sort not sorting all elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, while-loop

Trying to implement a simple bubble sort. Code is is as follows:

```
def bubble(array)
  start = 0
  sorted = []
  while start < array.length - 1
    if array[start] > array[start + 1]
      array[start], array[start + 1] = array[start + 1], array[start] 
    else
    end
  start += 1
  end
  return array
end

print bubble([4,8,2,6,7,1])
```

The output I get is:

```
[4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8]
```

Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: your `start` counter needs to reset somehow so you can continue to make comparisons. Right now your `while` loop only goes through all the numbers once

Comment: `else end` is redundant fyi; @philipyoo is correct, you need to repeatedly iterate through the array until no more swaps are done

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you intend to make use of `sorted`, you should avoid modifying `array` and instead use a copy. You need to repeatedly iterate through the array until no more items are out of order, something like:

```
def bubble(array)
  sorted = array.dup
  finished = false
  until finished
    start = 0
    finished = true
    while start < sorted.length - 1
      if sorted[start] > sorted[start + 1]
        sorted[start], sorted[start + 1] = sorted[start + 1], sorted[start]
        finished = false
      end
      start += 1
    end
  end
  return sorted
end
```

although I'd make the point of mentioning that explicit `return` is relatively unpopular in Ruby; you can simply leave `sorted` as the last line for identical semantics.